# How to write simple async method?

Tags: c#, async-ctp

Using latest CTP5 with async/await keywords, I wrote some code, which apparently cannot compile:

```
 class Program
    {
        public class MyClass
        {
            async public Task<int> Test()
            {
                var result = await TaskEx.Run(() =>
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(3000);
                        return 3;
                    });
                return result;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myClass = new MyClass();

            //The 'await' operator can only be used in a method or lambda marked with the 'async' modifier error ??!!
            int result = await myClass.Test();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

What is th reason of "The 'await' operator can only be used in a method or lambda marked with the 'async' modifier error?" (I've selected the line which Visual Studio point me to)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if you can mark Main as async, but you need to include the `async` keyword in the declaration of any method that uses `await`.  For example:

```
public async void DoStuffAsync ()
{
    var myClass = new MyClass ();

    int result = await myClass.TestAsync ();
}
```

Comment: You *can* declare `Main` as `async`, and `await`ing anything in it *will* end your program (assuming you have no other foreground threads running.)

Comment: Duh, I kept thinking that the error is inside my Test method. The Visual Studio should be more informative with this error (like "method Main must async")

Comment: In the C#5 release, if you mark Main as async, you get an error: "An entry point cannot be marked with the 'async' modifier"

Answer (score 4):

`await` is not the same as `Wait()`; doing an `await` is a significant re-writing of that method, and in particular affects the expectation of how that method exits to the caller. You are right in that it doesn't actually *do* much (caveat: return types) except tell the compiler to enable some things (as do switches like `unsafe`, `checked` and `unchecked` if you think about it) - but consider: this actually matters ***hugely*** in your example. If `Main()` exits (and we assume no other threads) - you exe *is toast*. Gone. No longer exists. Adding `async` makes you consider that just because the method *exits* doesn't mean it has *finished*. You really don't want `Main()` exiting before you are ready.

As a secondary effect, this switch also formalises that the method can only return things like `Task`; without the switch, you might be tempted to make it async later, which could be a significantly breaking change.

Comment: @dlev nice Monty Python there ;p

Answer (score 4):

An async method can have a return type of void or Task. If the return type is not void the caller can still use the standard Wait mechanism introduced in .Net 4 inside the Main entry method (which can not be marked async). Here's a simple example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string address = "http://api.worldbank.org/countries?format=json";
        Task t = LoadJsonAsync(address);
        // do other work while loading
        t.Wait();

        Console.WriteLine("Hit ENTER to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private async static Task LoadJsonAsync(string address)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(address);

        // Check that response was successful or throw exception
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        // Read response asynchronously as JsonValue and write out top facts for each country
        JsonArray readTask = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JsonArray>();
        Console.WriteLine("First 50 countries listed by The World Bank...");
        foreach (var country in readTask[1])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   {0}, Capital: {1}",
                country.Value["name"],
                country.Value["capitalCity"]);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I hate how everyone always uses client.GetAsync as the example.  The poster probably knows how to use someone else's async method.  How do you *write* one?? (for example using the Sleep example)

Comment: What if your async task returns a result? Calling task.wait returns a boolean. How would you go about waiting and then using the returned result?   EDIT: Never mind. `Task.Result`.

Comment: not sure, but don't you need to start Task t before Wait()-ing for it? `t.Start(); t.Wait();`