# Write async method correctly

Tags: c#, asynchronous, methods, async-await, task-parallel-library

I've used async methods for a long time, but I don't know the right way to write my own async method. As I get it, first root(I mean most deep) async method begins from sync method wrapped in a Task? Am I right? What is the right pattern to write such methods? Right now I do it like this:

```
private async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
    var tsk = new Task(OnDo);
    tsk.Start();
    await tsk.ConfigureAwait(false);
}

private void OnDo()
{
    // Do stuff ...
}
```

Comment: If the 'root' method is synchronous, it's synchronous.  Don't fake async by just running it on another thread.  See [this blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html) for more detail

Comment: A good answer would be pages long. I think you need to read a few basi tutorials.

Comment: @CharlesMager, great article, that explains much. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24954336/1870803) can shed some light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual answer is too long to post here.

### Short answer

No, you should not call async methods from sync methods. The method tree should be asynchronous bottom to top.

For example: Using ASP.NET MVC async methods would be called from async Action methods, see: [Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4).

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GizmosAsync()
{
    ViewBag.SyncOrAsync = "Asynchronous";
    var gizmoService = new GizmoService();
    return View("Gizmos", await gizmoService.GetGizmosAsync());
}
```

Using WPF applications, you should have async void event methods, that call your asynchronous methods.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    textBlock1.Text = "Click Started";
    await DoWork();
    textBlock2.Text = "Click Finished";
}
```

Either way, the question is too broad.

- What is your "to be implemented" method?
- why do you want it to be async?
- What environment are you using?

**In general async is used for I/O operations(databases, network, file read/write) or parallelism.**